# XSL Transformation: Get element by ID from variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I am parsing a XML file with different elements to build a CSV. I iterate through persons like this

```
<xsl:template match="/root/persons/person"> 
     <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:variable name="refId">
           <xsl:value-of select="role/@refId"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- This is the problematic part -->
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/roles/role[@id='$refId']"/>

        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In my person element I have a refId that refers to the ID of a role element. How can I get the role name with the refId loaded into a variable like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/roles/role[@id=string($refId)]"/>
```

I'm supposing that your path is correct, since we can't see your XML to validate.

Comment: @juergend You're welcome :) I had this problem literally yesterday, but can't find the SO answer that helped me then.